# Passing query string parameters to Lambda Function via API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've managed to create a Lambda function which returns some data, in JSON format which I've managed to invoke via AWS Lambda calls from JavaScript.

I've since then created an API Gateway, which in turn calls the same Lambda function and have successfully managed to retrieve data, again, in JSON format.

Although it's taken a while to understand the mappings, Lambda Integrations, etc, I now have my webpage retrieving JSON from a Lambda Function which is invoked from the API Gateway. So far so good.

However, a few of my methods in the Lambda Function require parameters, and while I'm not getting any errors, when these are invoked I receive nothing.

For example, if I call:

```
https://mygatewayaddress/v1/test?e=getUserNames
```

Then it works fine.

However if I try to run:

```
https://mygatewayaddress/v1/test?e=getUserNames&sex=male
```

I don't get anything back whatsoever.  I've even tried to hardcode "sex":"male" in the mapping template to test things, but still, I get nothing back.

Is there anything obvious to check?  Anything that I may need to change for these additional parameters to be passed to my Lambda Function.

Like I said, the call is run, I'm getting back the standard JSON Payload from my Lambda, just the recordset is totally empty.

Comment: You really need to show the Lambda function code, and probably your mapping template, in order for this question to be answerable. Also, when you don't receive a response, what does the corresponding Lambda execution log look like in CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: Which language you are using?

Comment: Does your API define this query parameter for the resource?  Have you deployed the API after updating the hard-coded mapping you mentioned?